# Does OpenDaylight RESTCONF support HTTP PUT or POST methods?

Tags: postman, opendaylight, openvswitch, ietf-restconf

I am using opendaylight(oxygen) as a controller connecting to openvswitch(2.9.0) on ubuntu(18.40).

I was trying to add flow to OVS by DLUX-Yangman, but I found that there is only a Get method to choose, no Put, Post, or Delete.

Currently, I have only installed 3 features: odl-restconf odl-dluxapps-applications odl-l2switch-switch-ui

When I use postman to put flow to controller:

http://192.168.68.129:8181/restconf/operational/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node/{id}/flow-node-inventory:table/{id}/flow/{id}

I always get the returned status: **405 methods not allowed**.

Comment: I used the wrong url. the right url should be http://192.168.68.129:8181/restconf/config/opendaylight-inventory/...
but I can not find "config" option under opendaylight-inventory in Yangman?
plus, after I upload the flow using postman and get status: 201 created, I still can't find the flow using Get method. Why?

Comment: just in case it helps to understand what is what, you are using RESTCONF not DLUX here

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write to the operational data store - you cannot do that via restconf - operational data is read-only. Only the config data store can be updated.

Comment: I used the wrong url. the right url should be 192.168.68.129:8181/restconf/config/opendaylight-inventory... but I can not find "config" option under opendaylight-inventory in Yangman? plus, after I upload the flow using postman and get status: 201 created, I still can't find the flow using Get method. Why?